# Do printshops charge more to non-designer clients?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, print-design, print-production, editorial-design

Whenever I go to a printshop I try to give them the most suitable and high quality print-ready files, so that they do not need to take any extra steps or adjust things on the way (although they sometimes need).

On the other hand, someone that is not a designer/artist may not know how to give the best setup and printshops would need to tweak things in order to fit their printer needs.

Then a question comes to my mind:

**Do printshops actually charge more to non-designer customers due to that extra work?**

Makes sense as time is money, but, is this actually true?

I have had non-designer friends who paid more for simillar things that I did for much less money.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being a designer or not. If extra work needs to be done, your printer will charge you extra.  This is the same in any industry.  If you ask someone to paint your house, and there is an extra room you forgot to mention when you got your quote, they won't paint it for free.

Answer (score 3):

If more work is required to prepare a file for reproduction, then *of course* there would be additional fees associated with that extra work.

It has little or nothing to do with being, or not being, a designer. It's based on the file and technical requirements to reproduce the file.